# Sequence of execution for closures

Tags: r, closures, lapply

Here's a test function I created to learn how `lapply` and closures interact. My objective is to iterate over `runif` function sequentially and print each iteration.

```
Mod_delay_by <- function(delay,f){
  function(x,...){
    Sys.sleep(delay)
    cat(".")
    #f(x,...)
    cat("Processing",x,"\n",sep = "")
    f(x,...)
    }
}
```

Now let's use `lapply` to call above function:

```
lapply(1:3,Mod_delay_by(0.1,runif))
```

When I call above function, I get the following sample output:

```
.Processing1
.Processing2
.Processing3
[[1]]
[1] 0.835246

[[2]]
[1] 0.1370997 0.4350032

[[3]]
[1] 0.1174749 0.4087628 0.7222604
```

I am surprised because all the three ".Processing" come before execution of `runif`. Instead, I would have expected the output to be ...

```
.Processing1
[[1]]
[1] 0.835246

.Processing2
[[2]]
[1] 0.1370997 0.4350032

.Processing3
[[3]]
[1] 0.1174749 0.4087628 0.7222604
```

...because `runif` (i.e. function `f`) is immediately preceded by a call to ".Processing"

Can someone please explain why `lapply` first finishes printing all the three `Processing`, and then prints all three `runifs`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `lapply` assembles whatever the function returns (the last line unless you use an explicit `return` statement) into a list and returns it. The `cat` calls are side-effects, which thus get printed as they are called, not upon the return of the anonymous function (when the returned object gets stored by `lapply`) or upon the completion of `lapply` (when it assembles all the results into a list and returns it, causing it to print if not assigned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the OP expects the output of `f()` should be *printed* to the console window in each call like `cat()` does.

Similar to what happens when the function is called directly from the console window:

```
> Mod_delay_by(0.1, runif)(2)
.Processing2
[1] 0.4519318 0.2331198
```

Please note that we won't see anything printed (except the output of `cat()`) if the output is assigned to a variable:

```
> result <- Mod_delay_by(0.1, runif)(2)
.Processing2
```

So, if you call a function from the console window and the output is *not* assigned to a variable it is printed to the console window.

---

Now, `f()` is being *called from within the body of a function*. This situation is different.

Instead of being printed to the console window, the output of `f()` is returned to the caller. The help file `?"function"` says *If the end of a function is reached without calling `return`, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.*

This can be made more explicit by writing

```
return(f(x, ...))
```

So, only `cat()`prints to console. The output of `f()` is returned to the calling `lapply()` function which collects all output in a list. Finally, this list is printed to the console *only because it is not assigned to a variable*.

If the output is assigned to a variable, we won't see anything printed except what `cat()` prints to the console.

```
> result <- lapply(1:3, Mod_delay_by(0.1, runif))
.Processing1
.Processing2
.Processing3
```

---

To summarize, R is trying to save typing but the outcome depends on the context:

- In the console window, `f()` without assignment implies `print(f())`.
- In the body of a function, `f()` as last evaluated expression implies `return(f())`.

Answer (score 3):

Function does not print anything to console by default.

```
.Processing1
.Processing2
.Processing3
[[1]]
[1] 0.835246

[[2]]
[1] 0.1370997 0.4350032

[[3]]
[1] 0.1174749 0.4087628 0.7222604
```

Here you are getting

```
.Processing1
.Processing2
.Processing3
```

because you are using `cat` and rest are coming from the `lapply` output.

If you change your defined function like this

```
Mod_delay_by <- function(delay,f){
  function(x,...){
    Sys.sleep(delay)
    cat(".")
    #f(x,...)
    cat("Processing",x,"\n",sep = "")
    print(f(x,...))
    }
}
```

and then run

```
lapply(1:3,Mod_delay_by(0.1,runif))
```

you will get

```
#.Processing1
#[1] 0.5281055
#.Processing2
#[1] 0.892419 0.551435
#.Processing3
#[1] 0.4566147 0.9568333 0.4533342
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.5281055
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.892419 0.551435
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.4566147 0.9568333 0.4533342
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Quick Q: why is it that `cat` finishes printing all three iterations and then `lapply` follows printing, as described initially in your answer? I didn't quite get this part. I'd appreciate your thoughts. Another way to think about my question: if `lapply` has already finished executing (as seen from "processing") why do we see those numbers being printed at the end? Is it that we iterate through the function twice?

Comment: No. You get it wrong. Quoting from `lapply` help page : "lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X" i.e. `lapply` will return a list at the end not in the execution time of the `function`. I think now it is clear the behaviour of the `lapply`.

Comment: Thanks again for your insights, research and willingness to help. I'm curious. How did you conclude that `lapply` will return the list at the end and not during the execution time? I read, re-read, and re-read quoted statement, but I am not following. The quoted statement, if I am not wrong, only states that `lapply` returns a list of `xyz` length. Where does it talk about the timing of printing? I am curious.

Comment: I actually got it...because `f()` appears at the end, R prints the output of `f()` only for the last execution of `lapply`. So, we see processing without those output for the first two.