# How do we return ggplot graphs through plumber web api?

Tags: r, asp.net-web-api, ggplot2, plumber

I was plotting a bar plot using ggplot and I created this function as a web api using plumber package in R.

```
 library(plumber)
 library(ggplot2)
#' @get /histogram_test
#' @png
  histogram_test <- function(){
  mtcars=mtcars
  b=ggplot(mtcars,aes(mtcars$cyl))
  b+geom_bar()
}
```

Then I run:

```
r <- plumb("plum_api.R")
r$run(port=8000)
```

But this does not return the plot on the browser.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469026/sequence-of-execution-for-closures/44470288#44470288) which tries to explain a similar problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it works if in the last line we just use the print command as:
print(b+geom_bar()).